# Как открыть ссылку в новом окне, закрыв старое?

Tags: javascript, html

Не подскажете, как перейти по ссылке, открыв ее в новом окне и закрыв старое. Зачем? Потому что старое окно маленькой ширины и без панели управления. А вот надо, чтоб при переходе по ссылке открывалась полноценная страница и закрывалось старое окошечко.

**Добавлено.**

Не подскажете, где я ошибся.

```
function focus(a)
{
    window.opener.location.href="/page.php?id="+a;
    window.close();
}

<а class="info" href="#" onClick="focus("9");">
```

Comment: @Ivan Не надо выкладывать код в комментарии. Нужно обновлять свой вопрос или задавать новый в другой теме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ЕМНИП parent - это только если окна вложены друг в друга (frame, iframe). Чтобы достать окно, которое открыло текущее, используют свойство opener, то есть в onload второго окна надо сделать что-то типа

```
if (window.opener) { window.opener.close(); }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
window.open('http://yandex.ru'); // открываем новое окно
window.close(); // закрываем старое
```

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('http://yandex.ru');window.close();">ссылка</a>
```

Comment: не работает...а если написать чуть по другому..то в некоторых браузерах просто закроет окно..

Comment: Opera 11.01: все работает.

Comment: Но сне ведь надо что работало везде!!И в хроме, и в мозиле,експлоуере!

Answer (score 1):

А каким образом было открыто это окно?

По идее, если окно открывается изначально через window.open(), то функция вернет объект открытого окна, через который можно его закрыть. Когда из этого окна нужно открыть что-то в родительском, то нужно использовать объект parent.

Как точнее работать с окнами можно почитать на javascript.ru, я давно с окнами таким бредом не страдаю :)

Comment: понял.спс.

Comment: Интересный вариант.правда надо погуглить.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.opener.location.href="/page.php?id="+a;
```

а если "opener" закрыл пользователь? лучше новое окно открывать.

```
onClick="focus("9");"
```

'9' - возьмите в одинарные ковычки

Answer (score 0):

Нет, всё немного не так делается. Для того, чтобы использовать `window.opener`, надо чтобы открываемое окно при загрузке закрыло своего "открывателя" - `opener`. Произвольную страницу так открыть не получится.

Поэтому в onload **открываемого** окна мы закрываем его `opener` - исходное окно, в котором юзер кликнул на линку (кстати, сама линка может быть обычным a href без onclick обработчика).

Чтобы уйти на произвольную страницу (например, не нашу - в которую нельзя добавить onload), надо по другому выкручиваться - попробовать добавить handler для события onload к значению, возвращаемому window.open. Кроссбраузерное решение может быть громоздким.